# cisco jabber "pull down" menu at top of window

Tags: jabber

cisco jabber 11.8.4

there is a supremely annoying widget that jabber places along the top of my screen. it can be slid left or right. no matter where i slide it, it is *always* in the way of something, usually a remote desktop session tab or a chrome tab. i'd like to make it go away permanently - i don't use and it adds no value but only frustration to my workflow.

is there a way to disable it? there's nothing obvious in the configuration that suggests so and the net is strangely silent. perhaps i'm not asking the right question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click the Settings gear, then go to View and uncheck "Show docked window"

https://collaborationhelp.cisco.com/article/en-us/WBX72624